# Is it possible to paste an image on a GLB file using Three JS?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I'm wondering if it is possible to paste an image onto a rendered glb file in the browser? 
For instance, I want to paste an image (png format) onto a rendered glb model in the browser on a click of a button. I am using OrbitControls js so the model will rotate, but I want the pasted image to also rotate with the model.

It's not like changing the texture itself, but simply given a size of an image, paste it onto the GLB model.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail your intended result? In general, the [three.js](https://discourse.threejs.org/) forum is a better place for questions with a broad character.

Comment: @Mugen87
Basically,
1. I have a png image (a sticker)
2. I have a 3d gltf/glb model of a macbook pro cover
3. I want to "paste" the png image onto the cover, like how you would paste a sticker onto a macbook cover in real life
4. Once pasted, the gltf and the png is basically "one file", and using OrbitControl I want to make the model and the applied png rotatable.

And thank you! I'll ask on the forum as well!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_decals

Comment: @Mugen87 YES! I mean I don't know if the paint spatters are images, but this is indeed what I am looking for!

Comment: Yes, the paint are textured meshes projected on the surface of the actual model. It seems this is exactly what you are looking for ;)

Comment: So [THREE.DecalGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/geometries/DecalGeometry) is the class you want to use.

Comment: @Mugen87 Awesome, I will look into this. Thank you very much!